# Finding region, between four hyperplanes, useful for integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, regions

Consider the function
$$
f(x,y,u,v)
=
\exp\bigl(
-x^2
-y^2
-u^2
-v^2
\bigr),
$$
and the region $\mathcal{R} = \cap_{i=1}^4 \mathcal{R}_i$ defined by four hyperplanes as follows
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathcal{R}_1 &= 
-((22843 s_1)/31868) + (14292 s_2)/29563 - (10538 s_3)/7331 + (
  13943 s_4)/12802 > 0,\\
  \mathcal{R}_2 &= 
  -((14321 s_1)/28058) + (20843 s_2)/23538 + (10097 s_3)/12866 - (
  27212 s_4)/17791 > 0,\\
  \mathcal{R}_3 &= 
  (22843 s_1)/31868 + (14292 s_2)/29563 - (10538 s_3)/7331 - (
  13943 s_4)/12802 > 0, \\
\mathcal{R}_4 &=
(14321 s_1)/28058 + (20843 s_2)/23538 + (10097 s_3)/12866 + (
  27212 s_4)/17791 > 0
\end{align}
$$
in code

```
R=-((22843 s[1])/31868) + (14292 s[2])/29563 - (10538 s[3])/7331 + (
   13943 s[4])/12802 > 
  0 && -((14321 s[1])/28058) + (20843 s[2])/23538 + (10097 s[3])/
   12866 - (27212 s[4])/17791 > 
  0 && (22843 s[1])/31868 + (14292 s[2])/29563 - (10538 s[3])/7331 - (
   13943 s[4])/12802 > 
  0 && (14321 s[1])/28058 + (20843 s[2])/23538 + (10097 s[3])/
   12866 + (27212 s[4])/17791 > 0;
```

I want to compute the integral

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-s[1]^2-s[2]^2-s[3]^2-s[4]^2], Array[s,4] \[Element] ImplicitRegion[R, Array[s,4]]]
```

or better yet

```
Integrate[Exp[-s[1]^2-s[2]^2-s[3]^2-s[4]^2], Array[s,4] \[Element] ImplicitRegion[R, Array[s,4]]]
```

However, when doing so I obtain the error message

```
NIntegrate::vedim: The number of variables 4 should match the region embedding dimension 1.
```

My guess is that Mathematica just gives up finding the reduced region and throws $0$ producing this output. Note that using `Reduce` supposedly reduces the complexity of the expression but while using its output as integration region produces the same error.

**Important edit**. Long story short; what I wrote in the original question was the actual answer: instead of using `s[1]`, `s[2]`, etc, I was using `Array[s,4]`. MMA did not expand it before computing the integral. Thus, I changed the original question to reflect this mistake and I will answer my own question.

Comment: My Mathematica instance, 12.1, produces a big piecewise answer for `Integrate`, and '`DiscretizeRegion` only supports dimensions 1 through 3' for `NIntegrate`.

Comment: @Adam, interesting. Note that I made a mistake writing the integral. Now it's exactly what I want to compute.

Comment: `Integrate` decides this one is too complicated, but no error.  `NIntegrate` warns that 'the global error' for 'GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times' and that its answer of 0.323116 may be wrong.  No system error though.  What's your version?  Maybe you could use Gauss's theorem to get an analytic answer.

Comment: Right. Apparently the problem was that instead of using `s[1], s[2],s[3], s[4]` explicitly, I used `Array[s,4]`. I will review my question and see if it's worth keeping it. Thanks for your help @Adam.

Comment: `ImplicitRegion[R, Evaluate@Array[s, 4]]`

Comment: @cvgmt yes, you're right! Thanks. Feel free to elaborate a little bit your comment as an answer.